# How can a coq Set or Type be a proposition

Tags: types, set, coq, boolean-expression, first-order-logic

I'm reading a tutorial on Coq. It constructs a `bool` type as follows:

```
Coq < Inductive bool :  Set := true | false.
bool is defined
bool_rect is defined
bool_ind is defined
bool_rec is defined
```

Then it shows what each of these things are using "Check".

```
Coq < Check bool_ind.
bool_ind
     : forall P : bool -> Prop, P true -> P false -> forall b : bool, P b

Coq < Check bool_rec.
bool_rec
     : forall P : bool -> Set, P true -> P false -> forall b : bool, P b

Coq < Check bool_rect.
bool_rect
     : forall P : bool -> Type, P true -> P false -> forall b : bool, P b
```

I understand `bool_ind`.  It says that if something holds for `true` and it holds for `false`, then it holds for all `b` in `bool` (because those are the only two).

But I don't understand what the expressions for `bool_rec` or `bool_rect` mean.  It seems as if `P true` (which is a `Set` for `bool_rec` and a `Type` for `bool_rect`) is being treated as a propositional value.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your intuition for `bool_ind` is spot on, but thinking about why `bool_ind` means what you said might help clarify the other two.  We know that

```
bool_ind : forall P : bool -> Prop,
             P true ->
             P false ->
             forall b : bool,
               P b
```

If we read this as a logical formula, we get the same reading you did:

- For every predicate `P` on `bool`eans,

  - If `P true` holds, and
  - If `P false` holds, then
  - For every boolean `b`,

    - `P b` holds.

But this isn't just a logical formula, it's a type.  Specifically, it's a (dependent) function type.  And as a function type, it says (if you'll allow me the liberty of inventing names for the unnamed arguments and the result):

- Given a value `P : bool -> Prop`,

  - A value `Pt : P true`,
  - A value `Pf : P false`, and
  - A value `b : bool`,

    - We can construct a value `Pb : P b`.

(Of course, this is a curried function, so there are other ways to break down the type into prose, but this is clearest for our purposes.)

The big important thing here, the thing that makes Coq work as a theorem prover while being a programming language (or vice versa) is the [*Curry-Howard correspondence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence): types are propositions, and values are proofs of those propositions.  For instance, the simple function type `->` corresponds to implication, and the dependent function type `forall` corresponds to universal quantification.  (The notation is pretty suggestive :-))  So in Coq, to prove that φ → ψ, we must construct a value of type `φ -> ψ`: a function that takes a value of type `φ` (or in other words, a proof of the proposition φ) and uses it to construct a value of type `ψ` (a proof of the proposition ψ).

In Coq, we can think about all types in this way, whether those types live in `Set`, `Type`, or `Prop`.  (So when you say "It seems as if P true (which is a Set for bool rec and a Type for bool_rect) is being treated as a propositional value," you're right!)  For instance, let's consider how we'd implement `bool_ind` ourselves.  We'll start by listing all the parameters to the function, along with its return type:

```
Definition bool_ind' (P  : bool -> Prop)
                     (Pt : P true)
                     (Pf : P false)
                     (b  : bool)
                     : P b :=
```

So far, so good.  At this point, we'd like to return something of type `P b`, but we don't know what `b` is.  So, as always in these situations, we pattern match:

```
  match b with
```

There are now two cases.  First, `b` could be `true`.  In this case, we must want to return something of type `P true`, and luckily we have such a value: `Pt`.

```
    | true  => Pt
```

The `false` case is similar:

```
    | false => Pf
  end.
```

Note that when we implement `bool_ind'`, it doesn't look very "proofy," but rather very "programmy".  Of course, thanks to the Curry-Howard correspondence, these are the same.  But note that the very same implementation will suffice for the other two functions:

```
Definition bool_rec' (P  : bool -> Set)
                     (Pt : P true)
                     (Pf : P false)
                     (b  : bool)
                     : P b :=
  match b with
    | true  => Pt
    | false => Pf
  end.

Definition bool_rect' (P  : bool -> Type)
                      (Pt : P true)
                      (Pf : P false)
                      (b  : bool)
                      : P b :=
  match b with
    | true  => Pt
    | false => Pf
  end.
```

Looking at this computational definition exposes another way to thing about `bool_ind`, `bool_rec`, and `bool_rect`: they encapsulate what you need to know to talk about *every value* of `bool`.  But either way, we're packaging up that information: if I know something for `true`, and something for `false`, then I know it for all the `bool`s.

The definition of the `bool_{ind,rec,rect}` functions abstracts over the usual way we write functions on booleans: there's one argument corresponding to the true branch, and one to the false branch.  Or, in other words: these functions are just `if` statements.  In a non–dependently-typed language, they could have the simpler type `forall S : Set, S -> S -> bool -> S`:

```
Definition bool_simple_rec (S : Set) (St : P) (Sf : P) (b : bool) : S :=
  match b with
    | true  => St
    | false => Sf
  end.
```

However, because types can depend on values, we must thread the `b` through the types everywhere.  If it turns out we don't want that, though, we can use our more general function and tell :

```
Definition bool_simple_rec' (S : Set) : S -> S -> bool -> S :=
  bool_rec (fun _ => S).
```

Nobody ever said our `P : bool -> Set` had to *use* the `bool`!

All of these functions are a lot more interesting for *recursive* types.  For instance, Coq has the following type of natural numbers:

```
Inductive nat : Set :=  O : nat | S : nat -> nat.
```

And we have

```
nat_ind : forall P : nat -> Prop,
            P O ->
            (forall n' : nat, P n' -> P (S n')) ->
            forall n : nat,
              P n
```

Along with the corresponding `nat_rec` and `nat_rect`.  (Exercise for the reader: implement these functions directly.)

At first glance, this is just the principle of mathematical induction.  However, it's also how we write recursive functions on `nat`s; they're the same thing.  In general, recursive functions over `nat` look like the following:

```
fix f n => match n with
             | O    => ...
             | S n' => ... f n' ...
           end
```

The arm of the match following `O` (the base case) is just the value of type `P O`.  The arm of the match following `S n'` (the recursive case) is what's passed into the function of type `forall n' : nat, P n' -> P (S n')`: the `n'`s are the same, and the value of `P n'` is the result of the recursive call `f n'`.

Another way to think about the equivalence between the `_rec` and `_ind` functions, then—and one which I think is clearer on infinite types than on `bool`—is that it's the same as the equivalence between mathematical `ind`uction (which happens in `Prop`) and (structural) `rec`ursion (which happens in `Set` and `Type`).

---

Let's get praxic and use these functions.  We'll define a simple function that converts booleans to natural numbers, and we'll do it both directly and with `bool_rec`.  The simplest way to write this function is with a pattern match:

```
Definition bool_to_nat_match (b : bool) : nat :=
  match b with
    | true  => 1
    | false => 0
  end.
```

The alternative definition is

```
Definition bool_to_nat_rec : bool -> nat :=
  bool_rec (fun _ => nat) 1 0.
```

And these two functions are the same:

```
Goal bool_to_nat_match = bool_to_nat_rec.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

(Note: these functions are *syntactically equal*.  This is a stronger condition than simply doing the same thing.)

Here, the `P : bool -> Set` is `fun _ => nat`; it gives us the return type, which isn't dependent on the argument.  Our `Pt : P true` is `1`, the thing to compute when we're given `true`; similarly, our `Pf : P false` is `0`.

If we want to use the dependency, we have to cook up a useful data type.  How about

```
Inductive has_if (A : Type) : bool -> Type :=
  | has   : A -> has_if A true
  | lacks : has_if A false.
```

With this definition, `has_if A true` is isomorphic to `A`, and `has_if A false` is isomorphic to `unit`.  We could then have a function which retains its first argument if and only if it's passed `true`.

```
Definition keep_if_match' (A : Type) (a : A) (b : bool) : has_if A b :=
  match b with
    | true  => has A a
    | false => lacks A
  end.
```

The alternative definition is

```
Definition keep_if_rect (A : Type) (a : A) : forall b : bool, has_if A b :=
  bool_rect (has_if A) (has A a) (lacks A).
```

And they're again the same:

```
Goal keep_if_match = keep_if_rect.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Here, the return type of the function *is* dependent upon the argument `b`, so our `P : bool -> Type` actually does something.

Here's a more interesting example, using natural numbers and length-indexed lists.  If you haven't seen length-indexed lists, also called vectors, they're exactly what they say on the tin; `vec A n` is a list of `n` `A`s.

```
Inductive vec (A : Type) : nat -> Type :=
  | vnil  : vec A O
  | vcons : forall n, A -> vec A n -> vec A (S n).
Arguments vnil  {A}.
Arguments vcons {A n} _ _.
```

(The `Arguments` machinery handles implicit arguments.)  Now, we want to produce a list of `n` copies of some particular element, so we can write that with a fixpoint:

```
Fixpoint vreplicate_fix {A : Type} (n : nat) (a : A) : vec A n :=
  match n with
    | O    => vnil
    | S n' => vcons a (vreplicate_fix n' a)
  end.
```

Alternatively, we can use `nat_rect`:

```
Definition vreplicate_rect {A : Type} (n : nat) (a : A) : vec A n :=
  nat_rect (vec A) vnil (fun n' v => vcons a v) n.
```

Note that since `nat_rect` captures the recursion pattern, `vreplicate_rect` is not a fixpoint itself.  One thing to note is the third argument to `nat_rect`:

```
fun n' v => vcons a v
```

The `v` there is conceptually the result of the recursive call to `vreplicate_rect n' a`; `nat_rect` abstracts out that recursion pattern, so we don't need to call it directly.  The `n'` is indeed the same `n'` as in `vreplicate_fix`, but now it seems like we don't need to mention it explicitly.  Why is it passed in?  That becomes clear if we write out our types:

```
fun (n' : nat) (v : vec A n') => vcons a v : vec A (S n')
```

We need `n'` so we know what type `v` has, and consequently what type the result has.

Let's see these functions in action:

```
Eval simpl in vreplicate_fix  0 tt.
Eval simpl in vreplicate_rect 0 tt.
  (* both => = vnil : vec unit 0 *)

Eval simpl in vreplicate_fix  3 true.
Eval simpl in vreplicate_rect 3 true.
  (* both => = vcons true (vcons true (vcons true vnil)) : vec bool 3 *)
```

And indeed, they're the same:

```
(* Note: these two functions do the same thing, but are not syntactically
   equal; the former is a fixpoint, the latter is a function which returns a
   fixpoint.  This sort of equality is all you generally need in practice. *)
Goal forall (A : Type) (a : A) (n : nat),
       vreplicate_fix n a = vreplicate_rect n a.
Proof. induction n; [|simpl; rewrite IHn]; reflexivity. Qed.
```

Above, I posed the exercise of reimplementing `nat_rect` and friends.  Here's the answer:

```
Fixpoint nat_rect' (P         : nat -> Type)
                   (base_case : P 0)
                   (recurse   : forall n', P n' -> P (S n'))
                   (n         : nat)
                   : P n :=
  match n with
    | O    => base_case
    | S n' => recurse n' (nat_rect' P base_case recurse n')
  end.
```

This hopefully makes it clear just *how* `nat_rect` abstracts the recursion pattern, and why it's sufficiently general.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer.  I'm still working on understanding it.  I didn't know about the Curry-Howard correspondence and I still don't quite get it. How would I use these functions directly (for example to define negation)? (the usage in the tutorial is encapsulated in "elim", so I can't find example where they're used explicitly)

Comment: In your definition of bool_ind, you have: Pt : P true, but isn't P true an element of type Prop.  How can something (specifically Pt) have a type whose value is of type Prop? Is Pt's type also Prop?  If so, what's the point of P?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your 1st question is asking.  How can you use *which* functions directly? On your 2nd question: every value in Coq has a type: *e.g.*, `O : nat` or `I : True`. But because Coq is dependently typed, types are just (special) values, so they must also have types: `nat : Set` and `True : Prop` (the types of types are sometimes called "kinds", esp. in non–dependently-typed languages). And those types must also have types: `Set : Type`, `Prop : Type`. So we have `Pt : P true : Prop`, just as we have `O : nat : Set`. The point of `P` is to pick out the particular proposition.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand what would be an example instance of P true? What is Pt?

Comment: My first question was asking for an example function call to bool_ind.  I want to see what all the arguments look like.

Comment: I edited my question to include some examples.  Let me know if that doesn't make things clear.

Comment: Absolutely.  Also I found a better tutorial (actually, it's a textbook) so now I feel like I'm starting to understand this stuff.  Would you mind taking a look at my latest question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17297165/403875 Thanks!