# Why must coq mutually inductive types have the same parameters?

Tags: comparison, coq, recursive-datastructures, game-theory, induction

Following [Arthur's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17304209/403875), I changed my `Fixpoint` relation to a mutual `Inductive` relation which "builds up" the different comparisons between games rather than "drilling down".

But now I am receiving an entirely new error message:

```
Error: Parameters should be syntactically the same for each inductive type.
```

I think the error message is saying that I need the same exact parameters for all of these mutual inductive definitions.

I realize there are simple hacks to get around this (unused dummy variables, long functional types with everything inside the `forall`), but I don't see why I should have to.

Can somebody explain the logic behind this restriction on mutual inductive types ? Is there a more elegant way to write this ? Does this restriction also imply that the inductive calls to each other must all use the same parameters (in which case I don't know of any hacks save hideous amounts of code duplication) ?

(The definitions of all the types and terms such as compare_quest, game, g1side etc. are unchanged from what they were in my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17297165/403875).

```coq
Inductive gameCompare (c : compare_quest) : game -> game -> Prop :=
 | igc : forall g1 g2 : game,
    innerGCompare (nextCompare c) (compareCombiner c) (g1side c) (g2side c) g1 g2 ->
    gameCompare c g1 g2
with innerGCompare (next_c : compare_quest) (cbn : combiner) (g1s g2s : side)
    : game -> game -> Prop :=
 | compBoth : forall g1 g2 : game,
    cbn (listGameCompare next_c cbn (g1s g1) g2)
        (gameListCompare next_c cbn g1 (g2s g2)) ->
    innerGCompare next_c cbn g1s g2s g1 g2
with listGameCompare (c : compare_quest) (cbn : combiner) : gamelist -> game -> Prop :=
 | emptylgCompare : cbn_init cbn -> forall g2 : game, listGameCompare c cbn emptylist g2
 | otlgCompare : forall (g1_cdr : gamelist) (g1_car g2 : game),
    (cbn (listGameCompare c cbn g1_cdr g2) (gameCompare c g1_car g2)) ->
    listGameCompare c cbn (listCons g1_car g1_cdr) g2
with gameListCompare (c : compare_quest) (cbn : combiner) : game -> gamelist -> Prop :=
 | emptyglCompare : cbn_init cbn -> forall g1 : game, gameListCompare c cbn g1 emptylist
 | otglCompare : forall (g1 g2_car : game) (g2_cdr : gamelist),
    (cbn (gameListCompare c cbn g1 g2_cdr) (gameCompare c g1 g2_car)) ->
    gameListCompare c cbn g1 (listCons g2_car g2_cdr).
```

In CGT, generally two players (named `Left` and `Right`) take turns playing a game where the player to make the last move wins.  Each game (meaning each position in a game) can be read as a set of `Left`'s options and a set of `Right`'s options written as `{G_L | G_R}`. When comparing two games, they can compare in any of four different ways: `<`, `>`, `=`, or `||`.

A game is `A < B` if `B` is strictly better than `A` for `Left`, regardless of who goes first. `A > B` if `A` is better than `B` for `Left`. `A = B` if the two games are equivalent (in the sense that the sum of games `A + -B` is a zero-game so that the player who goes first loses). And, `A || B` if which game is better for `Left` depends who goes first.

One way to check the comparison between two games is as follows:

- `A <= B` if all of `A`'s `Left` children are `<| B` and `A <|` all of `B`'s right children.
- `A <| B` if `A` has a right child which is `<= B` or if `A <=` any of `B`'s left children.
- And, similarly for `>=` and `>|`.

So, then by seeing which pair of these relations apply to two games `A` and `B`, it's possible to determine whether `A < B` (`A<=B` and `A<|B`), `A=B` (`A<=B` and `A>=B`), `A > B` (`A>=B` and `A>|B`), or `A || B` (`A<|B` and `A>|B`).

Here's the [wiki article on CGT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restriction is very interesting, and I had never encountered it before. I don't see any reasons for why this piece of code should be rejected. My best bet is that when people were designing the foundations of Coq this restriction made some of the proofs easier, and since not many people were annoyed by it, it just remained that way. I could be completely wrong, though; I do know that parameters and arguments (i.e., the ones that go to the right of the arrow) are treated slightly differently for some things. For instance, the universe constraints imposed when defining inductive types are less restrictive with parameters when compared to arguments.

Perhaps this should be forwarded to the Coq Club mailing list? :)

You don't have to put everything to the right of the arrow to get this to work. One thing you can do is to put everything but the `compare_quest` parameter to the right. When you use an inductive of the same type you're defining in a constructor, the parameter you give doesn't have to be the same as the one you give on the header, so that's OK:

```
Inductive gameCompare (c : compare_quest) : game -> game -> Prop :=
 | igc : forall g1 g2 : game,
    innerGCompare (nextCompare c) (compareCombiner c) (g1side c) (g2side c) g1 g2 ->
    gameCompare c g1 g2

with innerGCompare (c : compare_quest) : combiner -> side -> side ->
    game -> game -> Prop :=
 | compBoth : forall cbn g1s g2s (g1 g2 : game),
    cbn (listGameCompare c cbn (g1s g1) g2)
        (gameListCompare c cbn g1 (g2s g2)) ->
    innerGCompare c cbn g1s g2s g1 g2

with listGameCompare (c : compare_quest) : combiner -> gamelist -> game -> Prop :=
 | emptylgCompare : forall cbn, cbn_init cbn -> forall g2 : game, listGameCompare c cbn emptylist g2
 | otlgCompare : forall cbn (g1_cdr : gamelist) (g1_car g2 : game),
    (cbn (listGameCompare c cbn g1_cdr g2) (gameCompare c g1_car g2)) ->
    listGameCompare c cbn (listCons g1_car g1_cdr) g2

with gameListCompare (c : compare_quest) : combiner -> game -> gamelist -> Prop :=
 | emptyglCompare : forall cbn, cbn_init cbn -> forall g1 : game, gameListCompare c cbn g1 emptylist
 | otglCompare : forall cbn (g1 g2_car : game) (g2_cdr : gamelist),
    (cbn (gameListCompare c cbn g1 g2_cdr) (gameCompare c g1 g2_car)) ->
    gameListCompare c cbn g1 (listCons g2_car g2_cdr).
```

Unfortunately, trying to evaluate this gives a new error :(

```
Error: Non strictly positive occurrence of "listGameCompare" in
 "forall (cbn : Prop -> Prop -> Prop) (g1s g2s : game -> gamelist)
    (g1 g2 : game),
  cbn (listGameCompare c cbn (g1s g1) g2) (gameListCompare c cbn g1 (g2s g2)) ->
  innerGCompare c cbn g1s g2s g1 g2".
```

This error is much more common in Coq. It is complaining that you are passing the type you are defining as an argument to `cbn` because that could result in that type being to the *left* of an arrow (a negative occurrence), which is known to lead to logical inconsistencies.

I *think* you can get rid of this problem by inlining `compareCombiner` in the constructors of last three types, which may require some refactoring of your code. Again, I'm pretty sure that there must be a better way of defining this, but I don't understand what you're trying to do very well, so my help is somewhat limited there.

**UPDATE**: I've started a series of articles about formalizing some of CGT in Coq. You can find the first one [here](http://poleiro.info/posts/2013-09-08-an-introduction-to-combinatorial-game-theory.html).

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know.

I see the problem and I know how to get rid of it (albeit not without some code duplication).

I've added a description of what it means to compare two CGT games. in case you have any other ideas from that. Thanks again

Comment: Wow, this CGT stuff is really cool! Thanks for explaining it a little bit in more detail. I've posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/arthuraa/5882759) developing some of that in Coq, maybe that will help you!